# RPi SPI spidev python

Tags: python, importerror

I am trying to get data from sensors with mcp 3002.

I always get this error:

```
importError: no module named spidev.
```

I have tried the following:

```
mkdir py-spidev
cd py-spidev
wget https://raw.github.com/doceme/py-spidev/master/setup.py
wget https://raw.github.com/doceme/py-spidev/master/spidev_module.c
sudo python setup.py install
```

but got the error

```
spydev_module.c:no such file or directory
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define the path correctly.

cd \examplepath\examplefile\

Then install the module by `Python setup.py install`

Comment: i was using python 3 and it seems it has problems importing spidev. it worked just fine with python 2 .

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with python3 since it appears you have multiple python versions on your computer:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```